# useContext error when importing react components from custom lib using antd

Tags: reactjs, npm, antd

I have developped a local custom npm library that I use by using npm link.
This library export custom components and use antd library behind.

But I have one problem: when I use one of theses custom components, I have the following error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

I do not tried anything special. I have this problem when using simple components like spin or button.

I imagine that there is a context that is created by antd but I do not see how to tackle the problem.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.